# How are these expressions $\leq$ and not $=$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, bayesian

I am looking at these rules.  When the estimated values equal the expectations, wouldn't the terms in each case equal to each other instead of left $\leq$ right?  Am I missing something here?

[image: lms]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the simlar formulation

> $x^2$ is minimized when $x=0$. $0^2\le x^2$ for all $x$.

Comment: I see!  Makes sense now.  Thank you!!!